# Error al exportar base de datos a Excel con libreria PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Estoy tratando de exportar una tabla de mi base de datos a un archivo excel, utilizando la librería `PHPExcel`

La estructura de mi tabla es:

> reg, folio, clave, fecha, lugar, direccion, telefono, nombre, asunto, depto1, depto2, estado, observaciones, escaneo, evidencia

y mi código `PHP` para exportar es:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

 $conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");
 mysqli_select_db ( $conexion, "xxxxxx");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM solicitudes ORDER BY folio DESC";
 $resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion,$sql) or die (mysqli_error ());
 $registros = mysqli_num_rows ($resultado);

 if ($registros > 0) {
   require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

   //Informacion del excel
   $objPHPExcel->
    getProperties()
        ->setCreator("lahuerta")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("lahuerta")
        ->setTitle("Exportar Base de Datos")
        ->setSubject("Tabla")
        ->setDescription("Documento generado con PHPExcel")
        ->setKeywords("lahuerta  con  phpexcel")
        ->setCategory("solicitudes");    

   $i = 1;    
   while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_object ($resultado)) {

      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $registro->name);

      $i++;

   }
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tabla.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
mysql_close ();
?>
```

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error varias veces:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /home/exportar.php on line 32

También recibo estos 3 errores despues de el antes mencionado:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/exportar.php:32) in /home/exportar.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/exportar.php:32) in /home/exportar.php on line 39
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/exportar.php:32) in /home/exportar.php on line 40

y al terminar la lista de errores me muestra una codificaciones extraña:

> PKa�JG�D�X�[Content_Types].xml��MN�0���"�%nY ��vAa    �(0����ؖg�w{&i�@�nbE�{��y��d۸l m�����X�(���)���F��;@1_�����c)j�x/%��E��y� �QĿi!��K�y3�J<���Z1�0?Y�L%zV c��Ib7�����a/l٥P1:�q�r��j��j0A����u�""���(�  ���W�M��)Tj�({ܲ�>�O��,X٭���>B��~׭���Ӥ6�J=�oBZ����t��X4���Cg�,���QgmrL�ٯc�e��t�� Z�?����hPv��±��u�j���R������}�Cv��PKa�J�78�K_rels/.rels���j�0��{ �{���1F�^ʠ�2��l�$���-}

La versión de `PHP` es la `5.6` y la extensión `Zip` ya la tengo habilitada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema (`eg: Notice: Undefined property...`) se debe a que `$registro->name`, no esta definido. Esto lo se puede validar al ver estructura de la tabla `solicitudes`.

Luego los `Warning: Cannot modify header information...` aparecen porque previamente se imprimieron los `Notice: Undefined property...` y el método [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) debe ser llamado:

> Antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como include o require, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la función header(). Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo fichero PHP/HTML.

### Solución:

La solución debería ser simplemente modificar la linea `32`.

Suponiendo que el valor que buscas agregar a la celda es el `nombre` en la `solicitud`, entonces deberías escribir, `$registro->nombre`.

Ejemplo:

```
// "nombre" es uno de los campos de la tabla "solicitudes"
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $registro->nombre);
```

--

**PD**: Al finalizar tu `script` estas usando `mysql_close()`, cuando la conexión ha sido usando `mysqli_connect`, es decir, deberías usar [`mysqli_close($conexion)`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php). De todas formas esto no causa problemas porque esta justo después del `exit`, por lo que nunca llega a ejecutarse.